# How to register a domain when you have no phone number?

Tags: domain-registration, whois

Registering a .com requires a phone number for the whois records, but what do you do if you have no phone number?

(It's an academic question for me right now, but I did spend a significant amount of my life with internet access but no phone number. How do the deaf register domains or are they effectively excluded?)

Comment: You **have** heard of TDD, correct?

Comment: From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: I don't recommend it, but you could always simply lie.  It isn't like people actually check these things very often.  Send them to your local Pizza Hut.

Comment: Test driven development? (I suspect you had a different meaning in mind, so, no I haven't.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_device_for_the_deaf

Comment: @Zoredache - I've never heard it called a TDD, only TTY

Comment: Hello mods. Is this "off topic" because of it's academic nature (as ErikA implies above) or are the niceties of whois data off-topic for SF? (Not picking a fight. I just wish to learn what I did wrong.)

Comment: +1 just because of this awesome insight: "How do the deaf register domains or are they effectively excluded?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one of the temporary number services like [iNumber](http://inumbr.com/) or [TossableDigits](http://www.tossabledigits.com/).  You could also sign up for an Internet "phone" like [Google Voice](http://www.google.com/voice).

Answer (score 4):

Then give a false one, since there is no real need to have correct information on Whois. My personal preference is a string of 0's.